# Excel VBA to change Clustered Column Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I've coded the creation of a Clustered Column chart using VBA but need to set its style.

I can manually change the chart style by selecting from 2 variations of Clustered Column charts via the "Chart Design" -> "Change Chart Type" -> "Column" charts -> "Clustered Column" chart. One has colored columns with no X-axis data labels and the other has blue columns with 45° rotated data labels.

It is this 2nd variation I'd like to use but for both styles:

```
ChartObject.ChartType = 51
ChartObject ChartStyle = 201
```

and the macro recorder only records setting the ChartStyle = 201 for either style.

Any ideas how to distinguish the two variations using VBA or do I have to take the long route and set the data labels and rotate them and the column widths and the column colors?

[image]

Comment: `ChartObject.ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered` maybe? A screencap of the desired style might make it clearer which one you want.

Comment: image added but the substance of the question is how to distinguish between the two of them.

Comment: Try `ChartObject.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:D4"), PlotBy:=xlRows` or `ChartObject.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:D4"), PlotBy:=xlColumns`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Perfect! I have no idea why but does switch the styles as requested. Documentation is weak at best. 
If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the answer. 
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to change the style, but whether you plot the data by rows or columns

This can be done with:

```
ChartObject.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:D4"), PlotBy:=xlRows
```

or

```
ChartObject.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:D4"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```